# OpenMP filling array with two threads in series

Tags: c++, arrays, synchronization, openmp

I have an array. And I need to fill it with two threads each value consequently, using omp_set_lock, and omp_unset_lock. First thread should write first value,  then second array should write second value etc. I have no idea how to do that, because, in openmp you cant't explicitly make one thread wait for another. Have any ideas?

Comment: "in openmp you cant't explicitly make one thread wait for another" what about #pragma omp barrier ?

Comment: In favour of performance (which is why one would use multiple threads in the first place) neither using omp locks, nor including any thread waiting mechanics like barriers is desirable. You actually even do not need to lock the array if every thread is accessing a distinct set of values you'll end up without any race conditions.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why do you say you need to have `omp_set_lock`. Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do and maybe we can tell you a way to do it. Right now it looks like an [xy problem to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can use `ordered` to make one thread wait for another. I gave an answer but then deleted it because I really can't find a good reason to do what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the omp_set_lock/omp_unset_lock functions?

```
omp_lock_t lock;

omp_init_lock(&lock);

#pragma omp parallel for

bool thread1 = true;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    omp_set_lock(&lock);
    if (thread1 == true) {
        arr[i] = fromThread1();
        thread1 = false;
    } else {
        arr[i] = fromThread2();
        thread1 = true;
    }
    omp_unset_lock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: Thread identification is done using `omp_get_thread_num()`. How would your code handle threads 3, 4, 5, 6 if someone decides to alter the number of threads?

Comment: In that case I would use std::vector<bool>, as a resettable flag, in the place of bool.

Comment: That's needlessly complex.